# A bunch of related letters

Tags: pattern, wordplay, letter-sequence

Patrick is answering a series of questions where he is given a word and he has to write a single character. He knows how to answer these and quickly answers-

- `fsmss` $\to$ `s`
- `wsffs` $\to$ `0`
- `fwmhdhdbfw` $\to$ `m`
- `bsmhb` $\to$ `0` or `b`
- `dbmhsm` $\to$ `w`

While answering, he took a break. However, when he returned from the break, he forgot the process he found the answers, help him figure out the following-

- `fdhdbmhwmh` $\to \ ?$
- `bmhsmhwfwdh` $\to \ ?$
- `smhdfwsfdbmh` $\to \ ?$

**Note**

`bsmhb` $\to$ `0` or `b` means both `0` and `b` are valid answers. In case of multiple answers any valid one is accepted.

**Hint**

> Don't sweat over the wordplay tag, it really isn't necessary to solve the puzzle.

Comment: A single letter, or a single character? Is the '0' meant to be an 'o'?

Comment: he is given a word and he has to write a single letter -> Is the "0" meaning null ?

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat  A single character, corrected.

Comment: At first I thought this was going to be 'figure out what sequence was shortened to first letter', but then I couldn't match any.. (mtwtfs would be 's' - days of the week). Maybe it's just not first letters?

Comment: Notice that only the letters "B, D, F, H, M, S, and W" are ever used either in the sequences or the answers. I think this is a big part of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The letters in the sequences are all from the (alphabetically ordered) set `b d f h m s w`.

If we pair these up differently we get:

> h/w: husband / wife
>  f/m: father / mother
>  b/s: brother / sister
>  d/s: daughter / son
>  - note that "s" seems to stand for both sister and son.

The sequences he has already identified are:

> `fsmss -> s` : my father's son's mother's son's sister is my sister
>  `wsffs -> 0` : my wife's son's father's father's son is me (represented by NULL)
>  `fwmhdhdbfw -> m` : my father's wife's mother's husband's daughter's husband's daughter's brother's father's wife is (drumroll please) my mother
>  `bsmhb -> 0 or b` : my brother's son's mother's husband's brother is either me or my brother
>  `dbmhsm -> w` : my daughter's brother's mother's husband's son's mother is my wife

So the new questions are:

> fdhdbmhwmh -> **f** : my father's daughter's husband's daughter's brother's mother's husband's wife's mother's husband is my father
>  bmhsmhwfwdh -> **f** : my brother's mother's husband's son's [note: sister doesn't work here or I end up with my grandfather] mother's husband's wife's father's wife's daughter's husband is my father
>  smhdfwsfdbmh -> **0** : my son's mother's husband's daughter's father's wife's son's father's daughter's brother's mother's husband is me.

Comment: Actually, you don't need sister at all. You can replace sister by son, and the answers still remain valid, anyways good work, By the way, did you have a look at the title?

Comment: Huh, just noticed that, nice.

Answer (score 2):

The more I thought about this, the more I realized that it isn't right. Maybe it will help someone else though.

Given that:

- > 'w' can never follow an 's'.
- > 'm' and 'w' are considered matching (they're just upside down!).
- > '0' means there is no such letter, or adding no letters is sufficient.

Then:

> What letter from the set "b d f h m s w" when added to the front makes the front and back letters match?

fsmss → s

> fsmss → s (sfsmss)

wsffs → 0

> wsffs → 0 (since a w can not follow an s there is no letter)

fwmhdhdbfw → m

> fwmhdhdbfw → m (mfwmhdhdbfw)

bsmhb → 0 or b

> bsmhb → 0 or b (Adding no letters is fine here, but if you add a b you still match.

dbmhsm → w

> dbmhsm → w (wdbmhsm)

That leaves the answers as:

fdhdbmhwmh → ?

> h (hfdhdbmhwmh)

bmhsmhwfwdh → ?

> h (hbmhsmhwfwdh)

smhdfwsfdbmh → ?

> h (hsmhdfwsfdbmh)